# Why don't browsers send whether they have javascript enabled/disabled in the request header?

Tags: javascript, httprequest, detection, server-side

It just seems like something that would be really useful when developing server-side code. If you know that the browser won't be using javascript from the server-side, you could easily accommodate the user. Or if you just felt like it, redirect them to a page that says 'hey... we need you to use javascript for our application' etc.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: The question is "why", so it has nothing to do with programming, but if you had asked "how", I would have answered: You can write a javascript which will tell the server that javascript is enabled. If it doesn't, then it is disabled.

Comment: @zvone - that would result in 2 requests, and if one dares doing that on SO you get down-voted, and if you propose some solution you get down-voted too because it's not "perfect" .. SO used to be great, now it seems opinions win over fact ... geeks and their BS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `<noscript>` tag, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp).

I know it's probably not ideal (I don't have enough experience with it to pick it apart) but it certainly gives us enough flexibility to degrade somewhat gracefully.

Comment: Don't degrade -- *enhance* (progressively)

Comment: Well, let us just draw the line at _fallback adequately_?

Answer (score 1):

As handy as it would be to have your server be aware of your browser's Javascript capability before page rendering began, I can see a strange edge case such as:

```
// hide malicious code from people without javascript
if ($header['javascript'] == 'false') {
    show_regular_safe_website();
} else {
    use_some_nasty_javascript_exploit();
}
```

Comment: And what's to stop them from just using the javascript exploit without doing the check?

Comment: Because then people with Javascript turned off can still see that they attempted to exploit. :)

Comment: @argon what's the point of posting a rude comment like this on a question seven years old?

Comment: rude is a matter of perspective, and to answer: i stumbled on it because it's still accessible, simple; opinions matter, but controversial opinions backed with no sound reasoning is tosh.

Answer (score 1):

One way I use is to have a landing page/login page. When the user presses the logon button then use javascript to submit the results or update a hidden field before posting the logon. If javascript is disabled then the javascript will not work and therefore you can assume they have it turned off.

Answer (score 0):

The real reason is that when Netscape came out with JavaScript, they never thought to make the information available in the HTTP headers. Instead they created the `<noscript>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the Accept field could be used to such a purpose, like "Accept: text/javascript". But since it's proprietary the IETF would never include it in any standards and widespread adaptation is therefore unlikely. Web-developers has coped so far.

Comment: Not really. That would tell the server that it can send back JavaScript instead of HTML.